# Qt Line drawing to unexpected location

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to write a drawing program but I'm having problems with drawing lines.  When I draw a line on the bottom portion of the `QGraphicsView` the line is drawn to the center of the widget.  Why?  I don't think I understand the `mapTo` functions well enough, but the more I read the Qt docs the more confused I get.  Hope someone can help.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui  import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

import sys

class Main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        self.resize(300, 300)
        vBox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        view = View(self)
        vBox.addWidget(view)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            sys.exit()

class View(QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(View, self).__init__(parent)
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.stop = event.pos()
        self.line = Line(self, self.start, self.stop)
        self.scene.addItem(self.line)

class Line(QGraphicsLineItem):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args):
        # args = start, stop
        points = map(parent.mapToScene, args)
        (start, stop) = map(QPointF, points)

        self.line = QLineF(start, stop)
        super(Line, self).__init__(self.line)        

def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a   = Main(None)
    a.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't set a rect for your scene, one will be calculated automatically and the view will centre itself on the objects within it.

To fix this, add the following to the end of `View.__init__()`:

```
self.setSceneRect(QRectF(self.viewport().rect()))
```